# How to let DeckPanel to animate like sliding from left to right?

Tags: java, gwt

I am going to use [DeckPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DeckPanel.html) to give transition animation between two views.

However, when I move the views, one just moves from bottom to top or from top to bottom.

Can I let views move `from left to right` or `from right to left`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not easily possible with the `DeckPanel`.
You would have to subclass the `DeckPanel` and override the `showWidget()` method to support the new animation modes. 
Alternatively you could use the `DeckLayoutPanel`. It has an option to set the animation direction. 
See [here](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DeckLayoutPanel.html#setAnimationVertical%28boolean%29) for more details.

Comment: I tried to use DeckLayoutPanel. But it just doesn't show any of my panels. I have added to it.

Comment: Because `DeckLaoutPanel` is a `LayoutPanel` it must be added to `RootLayoutPanel` instead of `RootPanel`. Furthermore you have to have an unbroken chain of Widgets that implement `ProvidesResize` and `RequiresResize` up to the `RootLayoutPanel`. See the official [docs](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels) for more info.